# Java IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here? (comments are there to show you what the code does.):

```
/* -- GETS A WORD FROM A TEXT FILE -- */
public String getWord() throws IOException {
    String line;
    try {
        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream("HangmanGame\\src\\words.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); ) {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                return line;
            }
        }
        return line;
    } 
}

/* -- CREATES ARRAY LIST -- */ 
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (int i = 0; i < getWord().length(); i++) {
    char j = getWord().charAt(i);
    chars.add(j);
}

/* -- USER INPUT PROCESSING -- */
while(!chars.isEmpty()) {
    char choice = scan.next(".").charAt(0);
    // if(new String(chars).contains(String.valueOf(choice))){
    if(chars.contains(choice)) {
        System.out.println("You guessed right!");
        chars.remove(choice);
    } else {
        System.out.println("You guessed wrong");
        FailBuilder failed = new FailBuilder();
        failed.hangmanBuilder(1);
    } 
}
```

The first two blocks of code work as intended, however during the 'user input processing' whenever a user inputs a character then an `IndexOutOfBounds` Exception gets thrown. The code is meant to get a character from the user and check whether it is in the array list (if it is, it gets deleted and if it isn't then hangman is built (in separate class not shown here.)

Comment: Is there a stack trace?

Comment: Please provide stacktrace so we could diagnose the problem.

Comment: You are scanning for the next "." and then checking the first element. I assume that the scan doesn't return anything, as there is not dot and then it crashes because you are trying to get the first element of nothing. See here: scan.next(".").charAt(0);

Comment: the code is so bad indented ... and there is closed brackets which are not opened anywhere

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 117, Size: 6
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
 at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
 at Game.choices(Game.java:66)
 at Game.startGame(Game.java:33)
 at Game.GameIntro(Game.java:18)
 at Main.main(Main.java:8)
C:\Users\30141830\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)

Comment: @Secespitus ive tested this and it does return correctly, i printed the returned value and it showed correctly.

Comment: @azro I haven't included all of the code because it would fill the page. The excessive closing brackets are for closing classes that i have not included here. This was a copy and paste job, the actual code is indented with good practice. I have only included code related to the problem that i have stated.

Comment: @LiamRice Trimming the code is great, and thank you. But it's also common courtesy to clean it up when you're asking for help -- the issue isn't good practice, the issue is legibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List has several `remove()` methods.

You want to remove a char from the list (by calling `list.remove(Object o)`) but you are actually calling `list.remove(int index);` (because char is converted to an int by [Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)).

Example :

```
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add('a');
list.add('b');
list.add('c');

char choice = 'a';
list.remove(choice);
```

Output :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 97, Size: 3
>       at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
>       at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
>       at com.denodev.stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:22)

As you can see, `choice` is considered as an int which takes the ascii value of the character 'a' (97). Hence the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

With an explicit cast, it works :

```
list.remove((Character)choice);
```

Comment: Great, it works! thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the character to be removed instead of its position.
Use `chars.remove(chars.indexOf(choice))`.